# Can a scalar field transform nontrivially under a local special conformal transformation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Is there any way to have a scalar field that transforms non-trivially under *local* [special conformal transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_conformal_transformation)? Just by the index structure, I can see that the possibilities are

$$\begin{align}
\delta_K \phi &= \Lambda_{K}^\mu (x) \partial_\mu \phi \,, &
\delta_K \phi &= x^\mu \Lambda_{K \mu} (x)
\end{align}$$

where the subscript $K$ represents transformation with respect to the special conformal transformation, and $\Lambda_{K\mu} (x)$ is the parameter of special conformal transformations.

Considering the Poincare and dilatation transformations of the scalar $\phi$, I can see that both the first and the second possibilities are just orbital parts of Poincare and (inhomogeneous) dilatation transformations respectively.

Am I missing something? Is there really no way to write down a scalar that transforms non-trivially under *local* special conformal transformations?

Comment: Conformal transformations are those transformations which locally look like dilatations, rotations and translations, so there is no meaningful notion of "local special conformal transformation". If you think otherwise, could you explain, what a local special conformal transformation is supposed to mean?

Comment: There are vector fields, for instance, that tranasforms under **local** conformal transformations, i.e. you can check the non-linear multiplet of 4D N=1 supergravity, or the Weyl multiplet of any conformal supergravity, $\delta_K b_\mu = \Lambda_{K\mu}$. Those transformations **do not** look like local dilatations. So, it is possible and meaningful.

Comment: You still have not explained what do you mean by a local conformal transformation. Is this a coordinate transformation? If yes, how is it defined? If not, what is it? I am not saying that you cannot write down some formula for whatever supergravity, I am saying that the phrase "local conformal transformation" is meaningless without further clarification.

Comment: I am also puzzled by your mentioning of conformal gravity, since I thought that conformal gravity = Weyl-invariant gravity, and has nothing to do with any sort of "local special conformal transformations".

Comment: I assume that you know what rigid conformal transformation is. It is a coordinate transformation that solves the conformal killing equation. In the case of **local conformal transformation**, the parameters, both dilatations and the special conformal transformations are $x$ dependent. what do you mean what is local conformal transformation. Also, conformal gravity is, of course, invariant under the full conformal group. Weyl gravity is an example, but $-\frac1{12} \phi^2 R + \frac12 (d \phi)^2$ is another example which is not only scale invariant but invariant under the full conformal group.

Comment: Note that if you change the relative ratio between $\phi^2 R$ and $(d \phi)^2$ in the above example, you will still have a dilatation (or Weyl) invariant gravity, but not conformal gravity, since conformal symmetry fixes the ratio between these two quantities.

Comment: If you change the ratio, the result is not Weyl-invariant. Weyl invariance is not the same as dilation invariance, since it is invariance under local rescalings of the metric. As I mentioned, local translations are already the most general infinitesimal coordinate transformation, so I do not see how making parameters of special conformal transformations local give you anything new.

Comment: I agree that the local translations are already the most general infinitesimal coordinate transformation, but that does not mean making parameters local does not give you anything new. For instance, although $\delta x^\mu = \xi^\mu (x)$ is the most general transformation, the scalar field $\phi$ transforms as $\delta \phi = \xi^\mu (x) \partial_\mu \phi + \omega \Lambda_D (x) \phi$ under the local conformal transformations, so you pick up a term with local dilatations. My question is if it is possible to have a local special conformal term as well. Why would that be a problem in principle?

Comment: Well, then the distinction is in the action on fields. Here you basically write a formula which looks like local action of dilatation. If you want to write a formula which looks like a local action of any conformal transformation, it will be a combination of local rotation translation and a local dilatation, since this is how conformal transformations act on fields. It will perhaps be not most general such combination, but you already have the most general one from local rotations translation and dilatations. So "local special conformal transformations" should not bring in anything new.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand the question. How a scalar transforms is completely dictated by conformal symmetry. The transformation law is

$$K_\mu \phi(x) = \big(\Delta x_\mu + x_\mu \, x_\nu \partial_\nu -x^2 \partial_\mu \big) \phi(x)$$

or if you wish

$$\delta_K \phi(x) = a^\mu K_\mu \phi(x)$$

where $a^\mu$ are the infinitesimal parameters of the special conformal transformation. The above holds for a scalar primary of scaling dimension $\Delta$. As you know, you can also have scalar descendants, which will have more complicated transformation laws. For example, if $A_\mu$ is a vector operator, then $\partial_\mu A_\mu$ is a scalar but the transformation law will have one extra term coming from the $[K_\mu,P_\nu]$ commutator.

I hope this answers your question!

Comment: First of all, i do not want to involve more fields, just a scalar. when you consider the local Poincare and dilatation transformations, these terms simply become orbital parts of translations or dilatations. For example, in a global theory, a scalar transform under the Poincare transformations as $\delta \phi = \xi^\mu \partial_\mu \phi +\lambda^{\mu\nu} x_\mu \partial_\nu \phi$. However, when you consider the LOCAL Poincare transformations, you have $\delta \phi = \xi^\mu (x) \partial_\mu \phi + \lambda^{\mu\nu} (x) x_\mu \partial_\nu \phi = \xi^{\prime \mu}(x) \partial_\mu \phi$.

Comment: So the one that you had given, the first term can be placed into dilatation transformations by a redefinition of the dilatation parameter, and the last two terms can be placed into local translations by a redefinition of the translation parameter.

Comment: Maybe I understand your question better now. The reason this happens is that for a primary $[K_\mu,\phi(x=0)] = 0$, by construction. Then $[K_\mu,\phi(x)]$ is generated by shifting $\phi(x)$ using $P_\mu$. This means that all the terms in $\delta_K \phi(x)$ are generated by commutators of the form $[P_\mu,K_\nu]$ and $[P_\mu,[P_\nu,K_\rho]]$; it's of the form $K_\mu \phi(x) = \ldots D + \ldots P_\mu$. (For scalars, the generator of rotations $M_{\mu \nu}$ gives zero.)

Comment: @HansMoleman - You are implicitly assuming that $\phi$ is a primary field.

Comment: Sure. Otherwise you will have some terms coming from $[K_\mu,P_\nu]$ terms, which are again ultimately proportional to $\ldots D^m \phi + \ldots (P_\mu) ^n \phi$.

Comment: @JohnDoe, for example, here you write $\delta\phi=\xi^\mu(x)\partial_\mu\phi$, corresponding to $\delta x^\mu=\xi^\mu(x)$ and call it a local translation. However, this is the same as the most general infinitesimal coordinate transformation.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk , it is a local translation because the parameter $\xi^\mu$ is spacetime dependent. it is not a global shift i.e. $x^\mu \rightarrow x^\mu + a^\mu$ where $a^\mu$ is a constant vector. it is $x$ dependent.